# Unity 2d - How can I make particles inherit rotation from parent

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a particle system attached to a bullet and the particles being emitted are just rectangles. The problem is that when rotating the bullet, the particles don't rotate to face the same direction as the bullet.
[image]

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Does this help: https://answers.unity.com/questions/762742/how-can-i-rotate-a-particle-effect.html ?

Comment: It seems this is the same issue as mine but I couldn't get a fix. I tried setting the render mode to billboard and alignment to local, and I also tried enabling Align To Direction in the shape tab but neither worked. It seems I might be able to fix this by using a script that is constantly rotating the particle system but that's not really the solution I'm looking for. Maybe I'm not understanding how to use the particle system correctly since I just started. I'll try looking around at some tutorials later.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've looked around at some tutorials and I found that my problem fixes itself when I give the particle a texture. I had assumed I could do it without one given that I only wanted a yellow rectangle. To fix it, I went to the particle system and checked "Texture Sheet Animation" and switched Mode to sprites and assigned a texture. Then I went to "Renderer" and set Render Mode to Billboard and set Render Alignment to Local. Shoutout to Martin for linking that thread!